# how are these two pointers aliases?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, alias

I have these two pointers, **amen** and **ptr**, where all the values i assign to **amen** will also be assigned to **ptr**.

Can **ptr** and **amen** be aliases?

```
void func(const char *ptr) 
{
  struct samp *test;
  DIR *dp;
  char *amen;
  if(ptr[0]=='c'||ptr[0]=='C')
  strcpy(amen,"c_amen.txt");
  else if()
  ......
  else
  ...
}
```

so if **func** is called as **func("C");**, **ptr** will have the same vale as **amen** immediately after line 4.

Plus, what is **const** for? Shouldn't it be to protect **ptr** from being changed inside **func**?

Comment: segfault alert at line 'strcpy(amen,"c_amen.txt");'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot make any assumptions about the behavior as the following lines are incorrect:

```
char *amen;
// ...
strcpy(amen,"c_amen.txt");
```

You are passing an uninitialized pointer to `strcpy`, so you need to fix that (it expects that the destination pointer is valid and of appropriate size to hold the copied string).

After that is fixed, yes, `amen` would point to a string with the same content.  Of course, it is going to be cleaned up after the function call exits, so not very useful.  You need to pass in the size of the string or call `strlen` on `ptr` to figure out how large a buffer to allocate.

`const` in that context means that you cannot change the content that the pointer points to, i.e., the data is read-only.  The pointer itself is not const.